# Alternate for Datalist in winform

Tags: winforms

I am using window application for my project but i am facing some problem.I want alternative of datalist in window application for showing data.

Comment: can you share you've tried? or what error?

Comment: i am trying to show images in repeated form like datalist.Data is coming from database.

Comment: have you tried this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio//bb735936.aspx

Comment: no, but i don't want to use any other control i want only use window existing control.

Comment: you can use the `dataGridView` control http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview-tutorial

Comment: but how to set repeat direction and repeated number of columns in dataGridView